# How to display text within daterange UI in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

any help with this would be appreciated.

I am developing an app which uses the `dateRangeInput()` in order for participants to select their data. What I would like to have is some sample text appear when the user enters the app saying something like "please select date" rather than actual dates displaying.

I have tried using `helpText()` to do this however, I get the following result.
[image]

Could anyone offer a solution to this? I have also tried setting the `start =` and `end =` to be a string however receive and error due to them not being dates.

Here is some sample code below.

```
library(shiny)

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(

    fluidPage(
        sidebarPanel(
            dateRangeInput("daterange", "Episode End Date Range:",
                           start  = "2020-01-01",
                           end    = Sys.Date(),
                           min    = "2002-01-01",
                           max    = Sys.Date(),
                           helpText("Please select date"))
        )


    )
)

# Server
server <- function(input, output) {

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `helpText("Please select date"))` condition with `format = "Please select date"`
[image]

Although this is not perfect solution becouse every letter listed in avaible format values (https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/dateInput.html) is changed with its replacement. 
You might consider solving this by replacing word 'date' with synonym which does not contain letters "y","m","d"

Comment: Thanks for this, although if the string does not contain any of those date letters e.g `format = "Please select"`. The app becomes unresponsive.

Comment: Just tried adding another empty string format condition. 
App becomes responsive but displays date format additionaly
'...                        format = "Please select range",
                            format = "")...'